# password strength code help python

Tags: python

so i am writing code in python to tell you your password strength but it is not doing as i say and keeps saying invalid password password unless you use only numbers

```
hy=1
while(y==1):
passwordentered=str(input("plaese enter your proposed password "))
x=len(passwordentered)
numbers=passwordentered.count ("1"and"2"and"3"and"4"and"5"and"6"and"7"and"8"and"9")
lowerletters=passwordentered.count ("a"and"b"and"c"and"d"and"e"and"f"and"g"and"h"and"i"and"j"and"k"and"l"and"m"and"n"and"o"and"p"and"q"and"r"and"s"and"t"and"u"and"v"and"w"and"x"and"z")
higherletters=passwordentered.count ("A"and"B"and"C"and"D"and"E"and"F"and"G"and"H"and"I"and"J"and"K"and"L"and"M"and"N"and"O"and"P"and"Q"and"R"and"S"and"T"and"U"and"V"and"W"and"X"and"Z")
if(numbers>0 and lowerletters==0 and higherletters==0):
    david=9
elif(lowerletters>0 and numbers==0 and higherletters==0):
    david=9
elif(higherletters>0 and numbers==0 and lowerletters==0):
    david=9
elif(higherletters>0 and numbers>0 and lowerletters==0):
    david=8
elif(higherletters>0 and lowerletters>0 and numbers==0):
    david=8
elif(numbers>0 and lowerletters>0 and higherletters==0):
    david=8
elif(numbers>0 and lowerletters>0 and higherletters>0):
    david=7
elif(x>12 or x<6):
    david=10
elif(lowerletters==0 and numbers==0 and higherletters==0):
    david=10
if(david==10):
    print("the password you entered was invalid\
why not try again.")
    y=1
elif(david==9):
   print("the password you entered is very weak,try to include numbers, lower case letters and upper case letters. why not have another go.")
   y=1
elif(david==8):
    print("your password is good but it could be better try to include numbers, lower case letters and upper case letters. why not have another go.")
    y=1
elif(david==7):
    print("your password is really good. thank you for using this program")
    y=0
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: I recommend to read about regular expressions. It can make situations like this much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Python is  a very forgiving language, you can get away with a lot of stuff that you can't do in other languages, HOWEVER:

```
numbers=passwordentered.count("1"and"2"and"3"and"4"and"5"and"6"and"7"and"8"and"9")
```

Will not work. Python will evaluate everything within the brackets as a boolean expression and this line of code essentially boils down to:

```
numbers=passwordentered.count("9")
```

The same goes for the other checks as well. To get what you actually wanted from this, you should use a loop of some sort. You can use something like this:

```
numbers = sum( ch.isdigit() for ch in passwordentered )
```

This will give you a count of how many digits are found within the password string. You can modify this to count the number of lowercase and uppercase letters too.

Finally, you should try to clean up your if statements, you could break them down a bit more neatly and make this more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Those `count` functions won't work if written like that.

Try to replace this:

```
numbers=passwordentered.count ("1"and"2"and"3"and"4"and"5"and"6"and"7"and"8"and"9")
lowerletters=passwordentered.count ("a"and"b"and"c"and"d"and"e"and"f"and"g"and"h"and"i"and"j"and"k"and"l"and"m"and"n"and"o"and"p"and"q"and"r"and"s"and"t"and"u"and"v"and"w"and"x"and"z")
higherletters=passwordentered.count ("A"and"B"and"C"and"D"and"E"and"F"and"G"and"H"and"I"and"J"and"K"and"L"and"M"and"N"and"O"and"P"and"Q"and"R"and"S"and"T"and"U"and"V"and"W"and"X"and"Z")
```

with the following:

```
numbers = sum(typ in "0123456789" for typ in passwordentered)
lowerletters = sum(typ in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" for typ in passwordentered)
higherletters = sum(typ in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" for typ in passwordentered)
```

or the following for a verbose approach:

```
numberlist = "0123456789"
Lletterlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Hletterlist = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

numbers=0
lowerletters=0
higherletters=0
for f in xrange(0, x):
    if numberlist.find(passwordentered[f]) != -1:
        numbers = numbers+1
    if Lletterlist.find(passwordentered[f]) != -1:
        lowerletters = lowerletters+1
    if Hletterlist.find(passwordentered[f]) != -1:
        higherletters = higherletters+1
```